# Did Asta lose the Demon-Dweller Sword permanently?

Tags: black-clover

According to the Black Clover wikia,

> During his fight with Asta and Yuno, Licht reclaims the Demon-Dweller Sword[70] and displays greater control over the sword's magic absorption and release property.

Did Asta lose the Demon-Dweller Sword permanently?

Comment: I believe he will give the sword back to asta in the final fight with the devil...

Answer (score 1):

No he didn't. Even though we don't see licht giving it back to him, Asta later in the show and manga uses it.